# Alacritty cursor always block (█)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, fish

I reinstalled Ubuntu (LTS) yesterday and now my cursor in Alacritty is always a block (█). It works fine in Neovim but whatever I do it stays the same in my normal shell.

I tried it in fish, bash, sh, etc. I installed Alacritty using `ppa:aslatter/ppa` (both times) but for some reason it changed. I tried reinstalling it multiple times but it still didnt work.

I want the cursor to be a pipe in insert mode and a block in vim mode.

Normal mode: | (the normal cursor)

Vim mode:    █ (vim cursor)

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/v0.8.0/alacritty.yml#L370

Comment: https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/v0.8.0/README.md#configuration

Comment: Well yes this kindof fixed it but now its always a | and i want to to change to the block when im in vi mode i tried:
vi_mode_style:
    shape: Block
and

vi_mode_cursor:
    style:
        shape: Block

but it didnt work

Answer (score 4):

```
cursor:
  style:
    shape: Beam
  vi_mode_style:
    shape: Block
```

Make sure you *indent* the `vi_mode_style` sub-section accordingly as above under `cursor`.

Comment: The cursor is now | but it doesnt change to a block when i go to vi mode.
Also if I run nvim and exit it the cursor becomes a block again and it doesnt change back to |

Comment: Well for the second problem you probably want to file a bug report to alacritty upstream (on github). (It may have something to do with neovim itself; just see what they say about it first.) But at the very least, it works for me with 0.8.0 on Arch when I `Ctrl+Shift+Space`.